# How to make my template respect meta tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to override the DateTime template since I need custom class names on it.

So I have this in my edittemplates/datetime.cshtml

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "date-picker" })
```

// in my view model

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

So I am not sure how to make it just use my meta tag and use the date only. Yes I could hardcode it in and have Mode.ToShortDate() but maybe I will want ToLongdate() one time.

**Edit**

I think people are getting confused. First ignore the class name I just threw it in their to show why I am overriding the default datetime.

For me hardcoding these class names don't seem like a solution to me and that why I am struggling to figure out if I really want to use these templates and instead just go back to a using textboxfor().

The problem with that is then I have to change "Date" to a string as I only want to show the "Date" part. So now I have to later on convert the string back to a datetime so I can insert it into my db. With the templates I could leave it as a datetime and save a conversion.

For me it is weird to think that every datetime one will need the same class names and same html properties. These editorFor() should really take in html properties.

Second my whole post was this.

If I don't override the datetime template and do this

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

then the rendered result will only show the date part. Now if I override the datetime so I can add my custom stuff to it and do what I have above it will not respect the meta tag and will render the full datetime.

So my question is how do I make it so it uses the meta tag? Since not every date field that I have will only show the date. So hard coding something like that into the template would be dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just recreated your example and it appears to work as expected.

In your View are you binding the Date property as normal?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
```

If you have this then it should work as you want it to. However if it still isn't working then I can only think of trying one other thing. On your model add the following attribute;

```
[UIHint("ToLongDate")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Then create a new PartialView in your edittemplates folder called ToLongDate.cshtml and add the following lines;

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToLongDateString(), new { @class = "date-picker" })
```

Using this technique you could create various date format varitations and have each property using different ones.

Comment: Does this really work? Can MVC identify a template based on the call to ToLongDateString()?

Comment: Its not a call to ToLongDateString(), it is the name of a template you are supplying in the [UIHint] attribute. In this example it will look for a template called "ToLongDate" in Views/EditTemplates. I could have called it anything, but wanted to keep it relevant to the problem it was solving. So we could create another template called, "ToShortDate" etc..

Comment: And I don't really think this is the most optimal way to do it, what if someone someday decides that he need to have German, UK, USA and Japan's date format supported? Will you be creating *n* number of templates?

Comment: in the @Html.Text("", Model.ToLongDateString(), ...) it definitely is a call to that method..?

Comment: Yes, that is the call to ToLongDateString(), but that is not how MVC is determining which template to use. That happens using the [UIHint] attribute. And yes, I realise this is not the most eligant solution which is why I said it was the only other solution I could think of for the problem that was supplied. If you read above I confirm that I recreated the example and the implementation worked for me, so this was just something to try in order to identify the problem.

Comment: If this works, which I highly doubt it, you are essential hardcoding your DateTimeDate property in the model to the ToLongDate.cshtml template. I don't see how this is different from the original posters idea that he could just hardcode it in the template. You've just moved the *hardcode* from the template into the model.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to note that it doesn't even make sense that the OP has introduced new class name for DateTime, so this whole question is a bit off..

Comment: It does make sense in that all datetime objects will be injected with the jQuery datetime picker. A common use of this feature. But I do accept what you said about moving the hardcoding of the ToLongDateString() into the Model, a move that I wouldn't be too happy about using, it was merely an alternative if the original solution did not work, which I again confirm worked for me.

Comment: yeah, I understand the wire up of the jquery datetime picker, I use it myself. I just say, it makes no sense to introduce new class name for DateTime, like he does (DateTimeDate).

Comment: Im going to suggest that the OP made a typo and was meant to write public DateTime Date { get; set; }

Comment: @davidferguson - Yes that is a typo. I am going to edit my question a bit as I think ppl are getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is to use an overload of EditorFor() that accepts additional view data. You can use that overload to send view data to the template. You could send a date format string and then render the textbox like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString(ViewData["format"].ToString()), new { @class = "date-picker" })
```

Here are all the possible date format string
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Integrating with the jQuery UI date picker and adding a jQuery validate date range validator - Stuart Leeks - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but this maybe the answer you need. It's using custom attributes in your model that allow you to add html attributes to your view

[http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-*2D00*-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx)

Comment: Ya I seen that I am going to try it out. I was hoping maybe with overriding the stuff it would work but that does not seem possible. I will try what is in the post and see if that works but it seems like so much work since I would have to do it for strings,ints,datetime and basically anything I need a custom class name or html attribute.

Comment: Your right it does seem a lot of work for something that should be there by default. I would be interested in an alternative if someone else can provide a better solution